# Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

why does this code return false:

```
var text = "3b3xx";
if(text.match("/^\d?b\d+xx$/")) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

I can not see any problem with my regular expression.. I want to return true, if the string starts with any numbers, followed by "b", followed by any numers, followed by "xx".

Answer (score 7):

That's a string, not a regex.

Remove the `""`.

Comment: @groh Please watch the language. This is a classy place, and young people browse it regularly. And get some sleep. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a *string* where a *regular expression* is expected.

```
var text = "3b3xx";
if(text.match(/^\d?b\d+xx$/)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Actually, you can pass a string, and the `match` method will convert it to a `RegExp` object internally, e.g. : `if (text.match("^\\d?b\\d+xx$"))` but anyway, in this case is completelly unnecessary - since the pattern is fixed-,  I would even `return /^\d?b\d+xx$/.test(text);` to remove the `if` statement.

Comment: @CMS **and the match method will convert it to a `RegExp` object internally**": not in my Chrome it won't.

Comment: @KooiInc: Really? In which version of Chrome are you testing? Try: `'a'.match('\\w')[0] == 'a'`. If it doesn't work, it's *an implementation bug*, the behavior is completely described on the ECMAScript Specification ([15.5.4.10](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.10) - see Step 4 -)

Comment: using Chrome 12.0.742.112. But forgot to escape the escapes :}. Still, I wouldn't use this javascript 'dynamic typing feature'.

Comment: @KooiInc: Yeah, I just mentioned it because it's a little known fact, and the answer said that a `RegExp` object was "expected", in fact, you could pass any non-regexp object, it will be converted to String, and it will be used to build the RegExp object behind the scenes. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Why not trying this:

```
var text = "3b3xx";
return text.match(/^\d?b\d+xx$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just lose the quotes around your regex.

Regex is an object in Javascript, not a String.

`/^\d?b\d+xx$/`